# Styling an html table generated with php

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, dynamically-generated

So I have this html table that I want to style. It has php in it that gives the table its values (which is a bunch of select fields)

I may have done something wrong, the php works fine (it sends data to my database) but I can't style it with css.

```
<form action='processes.php' method='GET'>
    <table>
        <?php
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>COURSE NUMBER</th>";

        foreach($course_list as $cc){
            $c = str_replace("_", " ", $cc);
            echo "<th>$c</th>";
        }

        echo "</tr>";  

        while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_subject_results)){

            echo "<tr>";                
            $subjects[] = $record['Course']; //stores every subject in a list
            $_SESSION['Subjects'] = $subjects; //store the list in a session variable so i can use it in my processes page.             
            echo "<td>".$record['Course']."</td>";  

            foreach($course_list as $cc){

                echo "<input type = 'hidden', name = ".'pk'.$record['Course']." value = ".$user.'_'.$record['Course']." />";                    
                echo "<td><select name =".$kc.$record['Course'].">";                    

                foreach($eval_list as $opt){
                    echo "<option value = '".$opt."'>".$opt."</option>";
                }

                "</select>
                </td>";
            }

            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

It may have something to do with where I put the '< tr >' ? I'm so lost

EDIT: CSS (whoops!)

```
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
```

Comment: you have no style definitions or css classes on your html elements. where is your CSS?

Comment: added it just now! sorry i'm really new to this

Comment: Aren't the spaces in each side of `=` in html attributes screwing everything up ?

Comment: @Zyigh No, they are not.

Comment: where and how are you including the css here? the question's unclear in that respect.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i added the css. but if you mean how i added the css to the actual page, i just did `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />`

Comment: Your PHP creates invalid HTML. You are missing a `<td>`, so the inputs are not inside table cells. Also, you have a text "</select>
                </td>" that doesn't have `echo` in front of it.

Comment: check your path for it. Error reporting could help you here also. Edit: and/or what @MrLister stated in an above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So in  my honest opinion I would first change over the table to div tags. Now this is just me but this makes it a bit more easier to style. HEre is an example of how I would start off:

External Style sheet style.css

```
    #main-div{
        /*All Your styles Go Here if you dont know how to style refer to w3schools.org*/

    }

    .header{
        /*All Your styles Go Here if you dont know how to style refer to w3schools.org*/

    }

    .courses-head{
        /*Give this a width such as width:10%; or 20% or whatever 
        example:
        width:20%;
        Add more styles if necessary
        */
    }

    .courses-list{
        /*Give this a width such as width:10%; or 20% or whatever 
        example:
        width:20%;
        Add more styles if necessary
        */
    }
```

Your Actual Page:

```
<!--This goes in the Head -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/styles.css">

    <form action='processes.php' method='GET'>
        <div id=main-div>
            <?php
            echo "<div class='header'>";
            echo "<div class=courses-head>COURSE NUMBER</div>";

            foreach($course_list as $cc){
                $c = str_replace("_", " ", $cc);
                echo "<div class='course-list'>$c</div>";
            }

            echo "</div>";
```

Just keep following the layout that I started changing all the Table elements to .. Trust me at the end of the day it will make your life a hell of a lot easier. I used to do this exact same thing.

Comment: yeah i think i'll do this instead. it looks waaay easier. thanks!

Comment: Trust and believe when I say you are gonna save a lot of time. Also if you need any help with learning how to use style sheets or doc tags w3schools have extensive tutorials on how to use them.